# Find Max Possible Words that Fit into a Matrix of Characters

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, matrix, depth-first-search

Given a dictionary of words and a matrix of characters, Find the max number of possible words from the dictionary that you can fit into a matrix. A word can be fitted into the matrix if the word can be "assembled" from the letters in the matrix, and each letters can only be used once. Note that duplicate characters can occur in the matrix.

```
 [C A T]
 [G F I]
 [I N P]
```

Dictionary = `{"CGI", "CAT", "CFI", "ATI", "FNP", "CGI"}`

For this example, the result will return 3 because we can fit, CGI, ATI, FNP into the matrix at one time.

This is a small tweek to a normal DFS Matrix question, where you try to find a word in a character matrix.

I am struggling a bit to come up with a good algorithm to update the `bool[][] isVisited` matrix for this particular question. Since in this case, we only want to update the `isVisited` when a particular word is found.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Will Upvote and AC the first correct answer!

Comment: I was asked to do this in Java, but i think it is language independent.

Comment: I was just asking because leaving off the tag for the language may attract unwanted answers

Comment: what does it mean for a word to fit into a matrix? the words do not overlap?

Comment: DFS is not enough in my opinion, as you have to brute force all possible combinations. How big is your dictionary? How big the field?

Comment: Their sizes are both unspecified. It is given that there are more dictionary words than the matrix.

Comment: You should more clearly explain what "fitting into a matrix" means. My guess until now: It means that the word can be "assembled" from the letters in the matrix, and letters can only be used once - right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.